# Expandable ListView inside 4_level expandable listview

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I would like to know if it is possible to put an Expandable ListView as one child of one element of another Expandable ListView like that i want 4_level of expandable listview.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this github repo for n-level expandable listview : 
  [Polidea treeview](https://github.com/kedzie/tree-view-list-android)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You need to implement child expandableListView in its parent's adapter. Check out this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20609153/2065418