# listview items not filled the whole area(Expandable list view)

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

i am referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298155/issue-with-expanding-multi-level-expandablelistview/20609153?noredirect=1#comment30877644_20609153) to implement 3 level expandable list. the code works fine. but my problem is , the items in the child elements not filled the whole area. because of that i cant expand the next child element by clicking on it.(i have to click the exact area which is child element text appeared)

[image: here is the screen shot]

can someone point me, where is the issue?

i have edit my xml view also as `android:layout_width="fill_parent"`

but didn't worked..
please help me on this.
thank you.

EDIT

HERE THE ALL LAYOUT XML CODES.

**ROOT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ff5b5b"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemRootTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

**PARENT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#40e0d0"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemParentTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

**CHILD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#839096"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemChildTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**MAIN XML LAYOUT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
     >

</ExpandableListView>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show your rowlayout

Comment: show code of R.layout.item_child

Comment: set android:layout_width="fill_parent" in your row layout file..

Comment: @DigveshPatel  i have mentioned them in my question now..

Comment: @Erick  yes i did.. but didnt work :(

Comment: show your main xml file where you used expantablelistview..

Comment: @Erick I have added that too.. see my edited question please :)

Comment: i checked all xml file, didnt get any issue.. it can in your code..

Comment: @Erick  i have followed the all steps mentioned in that question which i mentioned in my question. only changed my xml file names. no any different... can you check that code for a while ? coz.. i have gone through every possible places that can be happen.. but i couldn't get it.. :(

Comment: Lena solved your problem..

Comment: @Erick yeah... but thanks for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encountered this problem with a spinner
I solved it like this

child xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#839096"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemChildTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" <== and this
    android:minWidth="500dp"  <=== add this
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

 </LinearLayout>
```