# How to expand partially list in expandableView Android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, multi-layer

I know similar to this question have already answers. I have some little confusion.

I want to create 3 layered expandable view (root->parent->child). But not all of my parent groups expand. I have 2 groups out of 5 which will expand.

None of the answers give me solution about partially expandable view.

Here is the link I referred

[link 1](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298155/issue-with-expanding-multi-level-expandablelistview/20609153#20609153), [link 3](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html)

Editing and suggestion are welcome.