# Is there any way to design 5 level expandable listview in android?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Is there any way to design 5 level expandable list view in android ? If yes then how. Please help me. Please

I was try a lot but fail
I want to design tree view but android is not support tree.

I have a oracle database. Where I make a table with parent child relation. I want to make such a tree where data taken from database table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes but then you have to calculate the height manually and pass that to each child list

Some other reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765638/how-to-display-more-than-3-levels-of-expandable-list-view

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should take a look at [AndroidTreeView](https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView) library, that is exactly what you want.

Comment: I was use this code before you sagest. there is an error.  How do I solved it.                    Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.2
Install Build Tools 21.1.2 and sync project