# How to scroll many ListViews inside a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio, android-scrollview

I work on an application that contain an XML file with some ListView I'd like to make them to scroll inside a LinearLayout, so i've done it with ScrollView but it's not possible, i need your helps, thanks in advance,  here is my source code :

XML-FILE :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ListViewCatalogueRDV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListViewDimancheCatalogueRDV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewLundiCatalogueRDV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/TextViewLundiCatalogueRDV"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/ListViewLundiCatalogueRDV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: list view it self have scrolling mechanism so do not  experiment with it.may be you are not feeling scrolling is happening due to less no of items in listview.so please make sure you have more number items in listviews..**no need to set**  **android:orientation=vertical**please remove it from   listview widget

Comment: yes i know that listview view itself have scrolling mechanism , but i need to make scroll my Linear Layout that contain many ListView,

Comment: I actually think you might want to rethink the ui that you are trying to build. Scrollable within a scrollable spells disaster, let alone ux problems. I would really advice you build the UI of your application differently.

Comment: Yes, me too i think so, thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found a solution, thanks for all your efforts (^_^), here is a solution : [stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210895/listview-inside-scrollview-is-not-scrolling-on-android/17503823#17503823)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765638/how-to-display-more-than-3-levels-of-expandable-list-view, it says for mutilist view you should use expandable listview

Comment: thanks Amit Vaghela

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use [ExpandableHeightListView](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView)

If you dont want to use ExpandableHeightListView than you can try following

**Never put listview in scroll view. Listview itself is scrollable.**

check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

> A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list

you need to use `weightSum`, check below layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ListViewCatalogueRDV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewDimancheCatalogueRDV1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </ListView >
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextViewLundiCatalogueRDV2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextViewLundiCatalogueRDV"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewLundiCatalogueRDV2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </ListView >
        </LinearLayout >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="TextViewDimancheCatalogueRDV"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/ListViewDimancheCatalogueRDV3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </ListView >
        </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout >
</ScrollView >
```

Comment: did you got solution ?@ZaK Amiar

Comment: NO i don't, i know  that we shouldn't put ListView inside Scrollview, so i look for solution to make scroll my Linear Layout that contain many ListView

Comment: listview doest need to put inside scrollview. i got your problem. you need two listview inside linearlayout right ?@Z

Comment: check updated answer in which your both listiview scrolls in linearlayout.

Comment: if still problem exist than provide scrrenshot of how you want ?

Comment: for example  i need 10 listview inside linearlayout, how to scroll the LinearLayout to reach the Tenth ListView

Comment: Thanks Amit Vaghela for all your efforts, i think i should  rethink the ui that am trying to build

Comment: i would suggest you to use **ExpandableHeightListView**

Comment: https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/ExpandableHeightListView

Answer (score 0):

In the very first `Linear Layout` set `android:orientation="vertical" android:scrollbars="vertical"`

Comment: it doesn't work !

Comment: then put the listView withinScrollView like `<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_city"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </ScrollView>`