# Expandable List View with three expandable groups

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a list of classes, for which the teachers attend those classes and list of students for those classes. I want to have a **ExpandableListView** for this such that the parent list view displays list of classes and total students, and on expanding, child listview displays list of teachers for those classes and total number of students, and finally child-child ListView displays the students who are taught by those teachers.
The List view should be something as follows:

```
    Class-1    Total Students=40   (First Level)
    ->TeacherName1  Total Students=20    (Second Level)
    --> Student 1                    (Third Level)
    --> Student 2
        .
        .
    ->TeacherName2  Total Students=15
    --> Student 1
    --> Student 2
         .
         . 
    Class-2    Total Students=50
    ->TeacherName1  Total Students=30
    --> Student 1
         .
         .
    ->TeacherName3  Total Students=10
        .
        .
        .
```

This must be a ExpandableListView with three levels of expanding and data is dynamic in nature. As the number of students may vary and teachers count also vary as new teachers join or leave the school.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ExpandableListView - Looking for a tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824074/android-expandablelistview-looking-for-a-tutorial)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765638/how-to-display-more-than-3-levels-of-expandable-list-view?noredirect=1&lq=1