How to Implement a Multi-Level ExpandableListView with Hierarchy: Plant → Department & Section → Line → Devices in Android
I am working on an Android project where I need to implement a hierarchical structure using an ExpandableListView. Currently, I have implemented a two-level hierarchy: Plant → Devices. Now, I want to expand this hierarchy to include additional levels as follows:"
Plant → Department-Section → Line → Devices
I want to extend my current hierarchy to support four levels: Plant → Department-Section → Line → Devices. Here's how the hierarchy should look
Plant1
   └── Department1-Section1
       ├── Line1
       │   ├── Device1
       │   └── Device2
       └── Line2
           ├── Device3
           └── Device4
   └── Department2-Section2
       ├── Line3
           ├── Device5
           └── Device6

I am not sure how to structure the data and create a custom adapter that can handle this four-level hierarchy. Since ExpandableListView natively supports only two levels (Group and Child),
I need guidance on how to:

Design a data structure to represent this hierarchy.
Implement a custom adapter to render this hierarchy in the ExpandableListView.
Handle nested levels like Department-Section and Line within the same framework.

I have considered using multiple ExpandableListViews or embedding a RecyclerView inside the child view for additional levels, but I'm unsure about the best approach for performance and scalability. I have not yet been able to integrate the three additional levels (Department-Section, Line, and Device)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765638/how-to-display-more-than-3-levels-of-expandable-list-view

Data Structure:
To represent the four-level hierarchy,we can use a recursive data structure like a custom class
public class HierarchicalItem {
   private String title;
   private boolean isExpanded;
   private  List<HierarchicalItem> children;

    public HierarchicalItem(String title){
     this .title=title;
     this.isExpanded = false;
     this.children =new Arraylist<>(); 

  }
  //getter ,setter 
 }

Additional point: Populate the rootItems list witj your Hierarchical data.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
